# How do I drop an index using Lucandra?

Tags: lucene, cassandra

I am using Lucandra and want to drop an entire index. The IndexReader and IndexWriters don't have all methods implemented so even iterating through a call to deleteDocument(int docNum) isn't possible.

Has anyone run up against this and either figured out how to either

1. hack the Cassandra keyspace or
2. made additions to the Lucandra code, or
3. figured out how to construct an iterator to delete all docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of lucandra doesn't store documents from 1-N so the deleteDocument(int) doesn't work.

What I've done is index a field with the same term in all documents so you can match all documents then delete them with deleteDocuments(Term) call.

Another option (if you only have 1 index per keyspace) is to truncate the cassandra CFs

The next version of lucandra(in development) does store documents 1-N fashion.

Comment: hey Jake, thanks, I've read your code and came to a similar conclusion. My concern is it seems that all docs might get read into memory at once.  My team and I are using Cassandra for our app's database as well and have created tools that will allow us to iterate through the key space column families. I was thinking I could just remove entries in Cassandra in the Terminfo and Document column families that start with the index name. I'd be happy to open source this tool. What do you think?

Comment: Jake, is the version that stores documents in the 1-N fashion the .7 Cassandra version on Git?